# R stuck after trying to register clusters with registerDoParallel

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

I have a piece of R code which never freezes on my laptop, but sometimes (~once per 100 times) it freezes immediately after "registerDoParallel(cl)" while running on the computational cluster. So, ages may pass - it will not move further. Nothing complicated with the computational cluster - just LINUX machine with 32 cores and a lot of RAM. It can freeze even when I try to register cluster with 1 core.

I have tried to use FORK or PSOCK clusters - does not matter, still does not work once per several times. It is pretty difficult to get anything meaningful from log files - it stucks immediately after this command:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
numberOfThreads = 4 # may be any number from 1 to e.g. 5
no_cores <- min(detectCores() - 1, numberOfThreads)
cl<-makeCluster(no_cores)#, type="FORK")
registerDoParallel(cl)

print("This message will never be printed if it freezes")
```

Does somebody have any ideas on why it behaves like that?

UPD: forgot to add - there are plenty of free cores and plenty RAM when this error occurs. Clear solution - https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/R.utils/versions/2.8.0/topics/withTimeout and repetitive tries to register cluster again and again - but this is sooo ugly.

Comment: Still have the same problem if your working session is empty?

Comment: Sorry I am not that proficient in R...may be I did not get the question, but these lines are the first lines of the script and the script is executed via `Rscript script.R` manner - not that I execute code line by line and may have something in memory...

Comment: The code works except once every 100 times? Probably because your clusters allocating threads to some other process that 100th time, like auto update.